# Is it possible to check whether Azure Active Directory user is allowed to authorize my application?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Our application allows users to authenticate via Azure Active Directory using OpenID Connect.

However, some organizations do not allow users to approve applications, and require administrators to approve the application first.

Right now, this means that if a user wants to connect using their work account, we have to first send them to Azure, where they then enter their password, and then are told that our application requires administrator approval. Not a great experience.

Ideally, I would like to give only users whose tenants allow them to approve new applications (or those that already have) the option of logging in via AAD. Is this possible to do through an API call?

Comment: Did you check my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does not provide such an API for this purpose.

As a workaround, you can quickly check it using [auth code flow: Request an authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code).

**Enter their password is necessary.** Sign in to this url with customer's credential:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read%20api%3A%2F%2F
&state=12345
&code_challenge=YTFjNjI1OWYzMzA3MTI4ZDY2Njg5M2RkNmVjNDE5YmEyZGRhOGYyM2IzNjdmZWFhMTQ1ODg3NDcxY2Nl
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

Then they can see if they need admin consent or not.

The essence is the same as the steps you described. But it can save a lot of time.

Comment: I don't see how this is any easier for the user, but "there is no api" might just be the only answer unfortunately.